# Trying to get my text fields to pass through as a FormCollection upon button press, but FormCollection is coming through as null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, formcollection

I have a View that contains automatically generated `input` boxes of type `text`.  When I click the "Email Results" button, the code takes you over to the EmailResults Action within the CalculatedResults controller.  So far, so good.  But, even though I have FormCollection as a parameter in the EmailResults Action, it's coming through as null, and I don't know why.  I need to be able to capture the text boxes from the form- please help!!.  In my View code below, the generated text boxes are a little past halfway down.

**My View Code**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EmailResults", "CalculatedResults", FormMethod.Post, new { data_ajax = "false" }))
        {
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Ingredient</td>
                        <td>Qty (gm)</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                @foreach (var i in Model)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToDecimal(i.Qty) < 0)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border: 1px solid red; color: red;">@i.Ingredient</td>
                            <td style="border: 1px solid red; color: red;">@i.Qty</td>
                        </tr>
                    }

                    else if (Convert.ToDecimal(i.Qty) == 0m)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        if (i.Ingredient.Contains("Active"))
                        {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@i.Ingredient<br />
                                <input type="text" name="actives" /></td>
                            <td>@i.Qty</td>
                        </tr>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@i.Ingredient</td>
                            <td>@i.Qty</td>
                        </tr>
                        }
                    }
                }

            </table>
        }
        <div style="float: left">
            @Html.ActionLink("Email Results", "EmailResults", "CalculatedResults", new { crpk = @ViewBag.crpk }, new { data_icon = "arrow-r", data_role = "button" })
        </div>
```

**My Controller Code**

```
public ViewResult EmailResults(int crpk, FormCollection collection)
{
    CapWorxQuikCapContext context = new CapWorxQuikCapContext();

    //List<string> variables = new List<string>();
    //foreach (var item in Request.Form)
    //{
    //    variables.Add(item.ToString());
    //}

    CalculatedResults cr = (from i in context.CalculatedResults where i.Pk == crpk select i).SingleOrDefault();
    Helpers.Email.EmailResults(cr);

    return View();
}
```

**Here's a screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formCollection will only come across when you submit the form to the controller. Either

1. Use `<input type="submit" value="Email Results" />`
2. Wire up a jquery handler to the ActionLink that you have created that submits the form for you.

Comment: Is it possible to send Route Values via a regular <input>?  I need to be able to send my @ViewBag.crpk value.

Comment: Not without having javascript construct the URL for you or change your FormMethod to GET.  You would still need to do one of the two options above, but it would do it via Route Values/URL instead of a POST.